# Wait async job in Powershell with Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-storage

I have troubles to run PS script as a Azure DevOps pipeline

```
$items = @($(codes))
$context = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString "$(connectionString)"
$queue = Get-AzStorageQueue -Name MyQueueName -Context $context
$makes | ForEach-Object { 
    $payload = @{"Code" = $_ } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    $msg = [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage]::new("$payload")
    Wait-Job $queue.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync($msg)
    Write-Host "Sent $payload"
}
```

The script works well if run it locally.
But in case if the same script run as a part of Azure DevOps pipeline

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
displayName: Send data to queue
inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(ServiceAccountName)
    ScriptType: inlineScript
    azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
    pwsh: true
    inline: |
      <script>
```

only first element is added to a queue. I suppose it's because process terminates before messages are added to queue.

How I can wait that async method completed before move to next one. Looks like Wait-Job doesn't work with Azure SDK method AddMessageAsync

I was found only one workaround it's add Start-Sleep 1 but it not enough efficient for me.

Comment: If you have to wait for the async operation, why not just call `$queue.CloudQueue.AddMessage` instead of `queue.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync` ? If you really need it async, you can use a _callback_ to get the completion status with `queue.CloudQueue.BeginAddMessage($msg,  New-ScriptBlockCallback ...)`.

Comment: I think you can define add a message as a job. Then start the job in parallel to add messages.

Comment: @Zilog80 SDK for PS has no sync methods;

Comment: Something is amiss. `$queue` is a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue` DotNet object returned by `Get-AzStorageQueue`, so it should have a `$queue.CloudQueue.AddMessage` method, PS or not PS. Did you get an _'unsupported/unimplemented'_ exception on call ?

Comment: Anyway, `$queue.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync($msg)` returns a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, not a `PSRemotingJob`. So `Wait-Job` won't do anything with it. If you want to wait for the task, just use `$myTask = $queue.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync($msg)` and `if ($myTask) { $myTask.Wait() }`.